Javascript question mark operator, multiple question marks
I get that this:
return A ? B : C

means
If A is true, return B, else return C
But how do I read this one:
return A ? B ? C : D : E

Not my code; I just need to understand it.
I've seen this answer/solution, but just saying "Javascript is right-associative, so you 'resolve' the ternaries from right to left" doesn't seem to answer the question.

You could read it as: "If A is false then return E, else if B is false then return D, else return C"

To clarify, A ? B : C is a ternary operator. Instead of A, B, and C, we can rewrite it as:
BOOLEAN ? EXPRESSION 1 : EXPRESSION 2
Depending on if BOOLEAN is either TRUE or FALSE, we will return EXPRESSION 1 or EXPRESSION 2.
A ? B ? C : D : E is a Nested Ternary. We basically have this:
BOOLEAN 1 ? (BOOLEAN 2 ? EXPRESSION 1 : EXPRESSION 2) : EXPRESSION 3
EXPRESSION 1 from our previous example is now (BOOLEAN 2 ? EXPRESSION 1 : EXPRESSION 2)
So, reading it:
When BOOLEAN 1 is TRUE, we return the nested ternary operator, and do a second evaluation (BOOLEAN 2 TRUE? return EXPRESSION 1, otherwise return EXPRESSION 2). However, if BOOLEAN 1 is FALSE, we return EXPRESSION 3

Thank you! Maybe I'm just old, but I feel that a lot of understanding is lost in making things shorter to write.

A ? B ? C : D : E is equivalent to  A ? (B ? C : D) : E.
It parses as A ? X : E where X is B ? C : D.

As for how to "read" it...the conditions are checked in order, but you can match conditions up with the values that occur when the condition is false in an outward-in nested rainbow manner. With the center value occurring when all conditions are true.  Perhaps a diagram would help:
A ? B ? C ? D ? ALL_TRUE : D_IS_FALSE : C_IS_FALSE : B_IS_FALSE : A_IS_FALSE
│   │   │   │    X         │            │            │            │
│   │   │   └──────────────┘            │            │            │
│   │   └───────────────────────────────┘            │            │
│   └────────────────────────────────────────────────┘            │
└─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘


In words, that would be read as "If the first thing is false then return the last thing, else if the 2nd thing is false then return the 2nd-last thing, else if the 3rd thing is false then return the 3rd-last thing, ... etc., else if everything is true then return the middle thing."
